# how to calculate a difference in a value between two documents

Tags: elasticsearch, request

I use Elasticseach to store water consumption data.

I receive a new document every hour, with a cumulative consumption value.
example:

- 20230914 00h00; consumption=100
- 20230914 01h00; consumption=120
- 20230914 02h00; consumption=130
  ...
- 20230915 00h00; consumption=199

I would like to store automatically the consumption of the entire day in a field. That is to say, make the difference between the value of day 1 at 00:00 and day 2 at 00:00.
Example : - 20230914 : total consumption = 99

How can i do that?

nothing, i am trying to find solutions

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that elasticsearch would need to retrieve the first record of the day for each record that it indexes. The would be a very inefficient and elasticsearch doesn't support that.

You can calculate that difference in runtime though using a date histogram with derivative aggregation.